# Select elements with variables in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I would like to know how to select elements using variables. What I tought would work was:

```
var class = "help-hu" // this value can change to "help-en" and "help-de" as well
$("."+class).fadeIn('slow');
```

But it doesn't work. Any workaround?

Comment: Please show us your html

Comment: @Asad this won't work, you will receive this in your console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word` but it's a newbie question to know which are reserved words or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check your `browser` console you will see this:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word

That means that you don't have to use this kind of words because they are `reserved`!

You can try another one and use the same logic like this...

**Example:**

```
var clazz = 'help-hu';
$('.' + clazz).fadeIn('slow');
```

This will work without problems.

Comment: @DJDavid98 yes, of course it does, because it does exactly what I told you 10 minutes ago.

Comment: I just tried to be more specific because I think you are starting with this.

Comment: @OscarJara you didn't actually explain that it was the use of `class` that caused the problem.

Comment: Well I am, but I still don't understand why I was not getting errors in the console.

Comment: @Alnitak the error describes that `class` is a reserved word, what more should I have to write?

Comment: So basically OP picked an answer he/she could copy & paste the code, instead of the answer that actually teaches how to fish

Comment: @DJDavid98 What browser are you using?

Comment: @DJDavid98 And when you press `F12` you don't see anything in console? Go here: http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/fXq2n/ it's your code and you will see the error I wrote here when checking the console.

Comment: @OscarJara the error describes that _something_ was a reserved word, it wouldn't have told him explicitly which one, and nor did your answer.

Comment: @Alnitak It actually does tell which line it's on in the code.

Comment: @Alnitak But happens when the code that contains `class` word is running, there is no extra code provided by OP to look if something more is wrong.

Comment: @OscarJara Because I'm sure nothing else is wrong, and provided this method, it works

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `class` as a variable name - it's a reserved word.  Use `cls`, or `klass`, or anything else that isn't a reserved word.

You *should* be seeing an error in your debug console...

Comment: Well, I didn't see any and my code was working. Not sure why then

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't but not because the class variable

Comment: @DJDavid98 some browsers _may_ let you get away with it.  Chrome doesn't.

Comment: @DJDavid98 and if your code is now working, what did you change?

Comment: I used what I posted in the answer that many people downvoted.

Comment: @DJDavid98 right, because it's a newbie answer.  And in so doing, you stopped using `class` as a variable, which is the reason it wasn't working before.

Answer (score 0):

As said your code works, but class is a reserved word. Have a read up on reserved words as it is useful information to know.

I've made a quick demo to show the code working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YSzTx/) and the code is:

```
var help = "help-hu"
$("." + help).html('hello, is it me you\'re looking for?');​
```